# Migrating to Aggregations from Date histogram facet builder with querystring

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

I am trying to migrate to Aggregations from Date histogram facet builder by going through following URL.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-migrating-to-aggs.html

I able to convert few queries to Aggregations and got proper results, however its throwing exception while converting following facet query to aggregations query.

Facet :

```
{
    "facets": {
        "lapp442.corp.com:timer_micro.99percentile": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "key_field": "@timestamp",
                "value_field": "timer_micro.99percentile",
                "interval": "30s"
            },
            "facet_filter": {
                "query": {
                    "filtered": {
                        "query": {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "lapp442.corp.com"
                            }
                        },
                        "filter": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": {
                                    "range": {
                                        "@timestamp": {
                                            "from": "1433145224508",
                                            "to": "now",
                                            "include_lower": true,
                                            "include_upper": true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "global": true
        },
        "lapp425.corp.com:timer_micro.99percentile": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "key_field": "@timestamp",
                "value_field": "timer_micro.99percentile",
                "interval": "30s"
            },
            "facet_filter": {
                "query": {
                    "filtered": {
                        "query": {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "lapp425.corp.com"
                            }
                        },
                        "filter": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": {
                                    "range": {
                                        "@timestamp": {
                                            "from": "1433145224508",
                                            "to": "now",
                                            "include_lower": true,
                                            "include_upper": true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "global": true
        }
    }
}
```

Aggregation :

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "lapp442.corp.com:timer_micro.99percentile": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "30s"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "metricstats": {
                    "stats": {
                        "field": "timer_micro.99percentile"
                    }
                },
                "host-filter": {
                    "filter": {
                        "query": {
                            "filtered": {
                                "query": {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "query": "lapp442.corp.com"
                                    }
                                },
                                "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": {
                                            "range": {
                                                "@timestamp": {
                                                    "from": "1433145293851",
                                                    "to": "now",
                                                    "include_lower": true,
                                                    "include_upper": true
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "lapp425.corp.com:timer_micro.99percentile": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "30s"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "metricstats": {
                    "stats": {
                        "field": "timer_micro.99percentile"
                    }
                },
                "host-filter": {
                    "filter": {
                        "query": {
                            "filtered": {
                                "query": {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "query": "lapp425.corp.com"
                                    }
                                },
                                "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": {
                                            "range": {
                                                "@timestamp": {
                                                    "from": "1433145293851",
                                                    "to": "now",
                                                    "include_lower": true,
                                                    "include_upper": true
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please correct me if the query construction is wrong while migrating this facet query to aggregation query.

Comment: "aggregations" should be replaced as "aggs"

Comment: Using AggregationBuilders in Java to create this query, so I think that wont be issue here